# Trying to make a List of Enums, but complaints about conversions to int

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to make a class, with has an property of tags. So that i can such the a list of these classes for all elements with a certain tag.

So i have made an Enum of tags, to make it easier to read. 
And then in the class i have a List of these Enums, but when i 
try to populate the list with the enums, it says that it can't 
convert tag to int. Does that mean that i have to manually convert my enums to ints every time ? or am i doing something wrong ?

```
     enum tag {tag0,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9};

    class Trait
{
    ...
    public List<tag> Tags;
    ...


    new Trait("a string", "another string", new List<tag>(tag.tag0)),
```

Thank you for any advise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add enum values to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940626/how-to-add-enum-values-to-a-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the constructors for `List<T>`.  The constructors that take 1 parameter take either an integer for the capacity or a sequence of values; the error has to do with converting `tag.tag0` to `int` for the capacity of the list.  That line should read:

```
new Trait("a string", "another string", new List<tag>() { tag.tag0 }),
```

This uses the empty constructor:

```
new List<tag>()
```

...which is followed by a collection initializer:

```
{ tag.tag0 }
```

Comment: This works, had not even noticed that i had used the wrong type of parenthesis. Thank you

Comment: I think it helps if you don't omit the constructor parentheses when you use a list initializer. Then it stands out more when your items are in `()` rather than `{ }`. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

> it says that it can't convert tag to int

Since in your example `List<T>(int capacity)` [has been used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_), it tries to convert your `enum tag` to the `int` in order to match the constructor but it fails as `enum tag` is not an `int`.

---

Try this:

```
new Trait("a string", "another string", new List<tag>{ tag.tag0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers are correct, so I'm not going to repeat them, I just want to add that if your class can have multiple tags you can also do something like this (instead of creating a `List<tag>`):

```
[Flags]
public enum tag
{
    tag0 = 1,
    tag1 = 2,
    tag2 = 4,
    tag3 = 8,
    tag4 = 16
}


public class Trait
{
    ...
    public tag Tags:
    ...
}

var trait = new Trait { Tags = tag.tag0 | tag.tag1 };

if ((trait.Tags & tag.tag2) == tag.tag2)
{
      // use & to check if tag exists
      Console.WriteLine("Has tag2");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Does not have tag2");
}

trait.Tags = trait.Tags | tag.tag2;   // use | to add


if ((trait.Tags & tag.tag2) == tag.tag2)
{
      // use & to check if tag exists
      Console.WriteLine("Has tag2");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Does not have tag2");
}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/17SFq8)